# Why setter injection does not ensures dependency Injection in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

In constructor based injection it will create complete object with all dependencies but How it will create object with partial dependencies in case of setter based injection?

Comment: A setter is a method call, there is no guarantee that that method will be called. With a constructor you simply cannot construct an object in an invalid state.

Comment: Spring calls a default constructor and then tries to inject values to this instance via setters. You won't see the difference. Anyway, you will get a well-constructed object.

Comment: @M.Deinum : as per my understanding, setters are called by default from spring then how can it missed?

Comment: Who says that only spring will construct your objects...

Comment: @M.deinum: that's what I am asking. I don't know how spring will invoke setter methods!!!!

Comment: No that isn't your question (at least not what I deduce from it). Why should it be only spring that constructs your object, the way you model your objects (constructor and/or setter based injection) shouldn't depend on the framework you use.

Comment: @M.Deinum : As per what I am getting from your comments is : from anywhere we can  call setter method and  set object so it  will go in inconsistent state. Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constructor based injection should be used when the dependences are required because the only way to create the object is having all of the arguments.

Setters based injection should be used when the dependences are not required. The object is first instanciated and then the setters for the dependencies are invoked, but, if the dependence is not found, it injects null.

You can mix both, Constructor and Setters based injection.

Comment: It does not inject `null`. For case when dependencies is not required it won't call setter at all.